# error trying to set production mode magento2.2

Tags: magento2

i have a magento 2.2.0 website and trying to change from developer mode to production mode gives me the below error

```
Command returned non-zero exit code: `/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin/php -f /home/stagesite.****.com/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US`
```

When I look at the var/log/system.log I see

```
  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse theme static file '/home/stagesite.*****.com/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog-OG/web/js/jquery.zoom.min.js
```

This js file is not modified in anyway so not sure whats wrong with it or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As per as your question, you are getting below error during static content deploy

> Command returned non-zero exit code

It means, in **your application/magento folder**, you have **some files which have zero byte size**, you need to delete those files.

Also, when you doing static deploy and di compile you need to set memory limit to  like

> /opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin/php   -d memory_limit=10G bin/magento
>   setup:static-content:deploy

*Here, i set memory limit 10 gb for this command.*

Seems,`Magento_Catalog-OG` wrong, maybe it would be **Magento_Catalog**

Comment: thanks but the jquery.zoom.min.js file does have content in it so its not zero bytes in file size . Maybe its a file that it references?

Comment: Thanks but the jquery.zoom.min.js file does have content in it its like 8,710kb in size. so its not zero bytes in file size . Any other suggestions how i can find the file that would be zero bytes?